# When is it best to define a copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm new to C++ and I was asked a question that I really can't answer: when is the best time to overload or define your own copy constructor in C++?

Comment: The purpose of the copy-constructor is to create a copy of your object.  If the default copy-constructor does not correctly create a copy then you should either disable it, or write your own one that does correctly create a copy.  If you never need to copy your object, you can disable it.

Comment: It is also necessary when you manage resources that require special handling when copying/sharing. Some background information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Answer (score 0):

If your Instance need deep copy, then your have to define the copy constructor. Copy constructor does only the shallow copy.
 As example if your class has a char pointer.

See this code example.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    char * m_name;
    int m_age;
    Student(char* name, int age){
        int name_len = strlen(name)+1;
        m_name= new char[name_len];
        strncpy(m_name, name, name_len);
        m_age = age;
    }
};

int main()
{
    char* firstStudent = "Kevin stefan";
    Student kevin(firstStudent,1);

    Student jhon = kevin;
    char* secondStudent = "Jhon Mac";
    strncpy(jhon.m_name,secondStudent,strlen(secondStudent));

    cout << kevin.m_name << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The result of this program prints `Jhon Macefan`. because both Student instance pointing to same memory location because of the shallow copy.

In this kind of situation you have to define a `copy constructor` for deep copy like this

```
Student::Student(const Student& stu)

    {
        int name_len = strlen(stu.m_name);    
        m_name = new char[name_len+1];
        strncpy(m_name, stu.m_name, name_len);

        m_age = stu.m_age;  
    }
```

Comment: I think this answer will only end up confusing people, even though your example is valid. As a counterexample, if the instance contains a `vector<int>`, then I (and I suspect, most) would call what the default copy constructor does a deep copy.

Comment: C++ does not really have "deep copy" and "shallow copy".  Either the copy does what you want or it doesn't. So-called "shallow copy" could be correct if the resource being pointed to is not meant to be deleted by the class.

Comment: @MattMcNabb That's one thing that this answer does cover correctly: "If your Instance need deep copy" -- it already acknowledges that there are classes that don't need it.